# Small program that disables Windows 11 upgrade cleanly and quickly so users can stay on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

Is there a program that quickly and easily disables the Windows 11 upgrade so that users can stay locked into Windows 10 indefinitely?

The gpedit/registry options are a little bit laborious and I'm guessing there must be a quick clean software tool that will implement this vs having to go through multiple steps as would be normal.

Comment: Windows 10 does not force you to install 11 even if your system is 100% compatible. And considering how Microsoft handled EOL versions of Windows you were never forced to upgrade to a new major version of Windows even if it would totally make sense. So users can stay on Windows 10 as long as they want even after 2025 (Support end of Windows 10).

Comment: I've seen it now with 4 computers of around 30 that I maintain at a specifics site. I wish I could believe what you're setting forth, but others appear to be seeing this too: https://old.reddit.com/r/WindowsHelp/comments/sbxrt0/windows_10_home_registry_edits_no_longer_stopping/hu6fdn2/

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to locate the specific newsletter from [Ask Woody](https://www.askwoody.com/forums/) as all my searches return a reference to single line registry edits, but a newsletter received in my email in the past month or so appears to provide what I'd consider an easy solution.

Windows 11 requires [TPM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/tpm/trusted-platform-module-overview) in order for the OS to be automatically installed to the specific machine:

> Trusted Platform Module (TPM) technology is designed to provide
> hardware-based, security-related functions. A TPM chip is a secure
> crypto-processor that is designed to carry out cryptographic
> operations. The chip includes multiple physical security mechanisms to
> make it tamper-resistant, and malicious software is unable to tamper
> with the security functions of the TPM.

I've found a [Tom's Hardware](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/does-windows-11-require-tpm-20-we-have-good-news-and-bad-news) post that suggests one can create a work-around to install Windows 11 on a computer that would not be supported (officially?) by Microsoft, but since your objective (and mine) is to prevent an auto-upgrade, that's not the important part.

I was able to change my TPM support to disabled. Granted, it reduces the security of my machine, but it also prevents MS from pushing an operating system to my computer.

If your computer does not currently support TPM, you shouldn't get the upgrade. If it does, check your UEFI settings under Security to see if you have the ability to disable it.

Comment: One problem I have in this scenario is that most of my clients are remote and so I don't actually have the ability to cleanly walk them through disabling TPM... This is an incredible headache and problem. Win11 forced updates have already destroyed two customers' work for some days costing them many thousands of dollars. <cries>

Comment: I had just that situation recently. Lucky for me, the other end had an Apple device and FaceTime was the solution for determining the correct UEFI entry to be selected.